# ASP.net MVC: Multiple domains, separate projects, separate deployments

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, architecture, mef

I may be searching on the wrong keywords, but I'm having a hard time finding a suitable solution for the following case. We have an internal application that has five separate business areas within the application. In the past, this has all been set-up inside a web site project, and we've piece meal deployed changes to this environment. We've always had issues with one change bringing down the entire site.

In order to mitigate this while also bringing easier ways to unit test and potentially get into continuous integration use cases, I would love to have a structure where all the transactions for particular business areas (domains) stay within their own separate project. The architecture may look something like:

- Main Project (Houses authentication, base master page, styles)

  - Ordering (Houses all things ordering)

    - Models/Views/Controllers
  - Pricing (Houses all things pricing)

    - Models/Views/Controllers

My question is how do I incorporate all this and give myself the ability to deploy each project separately at any time I'd like. So, for instance, I make updates to the Ordering domain, compile it, then upload the project without affecting the other domains.

Obvious other questions revolve around routing. How do I get the route correct? I'm assuming there are ways within the RouteConfig to set namespacing? What's the solution for this?

Is this what MEF does?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Areas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ee671793(v=vs.100).aspx):

> The MVC pattern separates the model (data) logic of an application
>   from its presentation logic and business logic. In ASP.NET MVC, this
>   logical separation is also implemented physically in the project
>   structure, where controllers and views are kept in folders that use
>   naming conventions to define relationships. This structure supports
>   the needs of most Web applications.
>
> However, some applications can have a large number of controllers, and
>   each controller can be associated with several views. For these types
>   of applications, the default ASP.NET MVC project structure can become
>   unwieldy.
>
> To accommodate large projects, ASP.NET MVC lets you partition Web
>   applications into smaller units that are referred to as areas. Areas
>   provide a way to separate a large MVC Web application into smaller
>   functional groupings. An area is effectively an MVC structure inside
>   an application. An application could contain several MVC structures
>   (areas).

(from MSDN, linked above)

Which would give you the logical separation, but not the functional.

To deploy **Ordering** without potentially taking down **Pricing**, the easiest thing to do would be to have separate web applications (which can be hosted within a single site if that's a requirement) for each. You can extract any shared logic to a class library project and reference that in both front ends.